# XML for TileSquare71x71IconWithBadge Template in Live tiles

Tags: xml, templates, windows-phone-8.1, live-tile

[Microsoft have a long list of great Live Tile templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx#TileSquare71x71IconWithBadge/), but no real guide on how to make them.  I am trying to put together the XML for TileSquare71x71IconWithBadge, but the example XML is missing from that list for this one.  What would that XML look like?  The closest I have gotten is this, but it does not work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<tile>
  <visual version="3">
    <binding template="TileSquare71x71IconWithBadge" fallback="null">
      <image id="1" src="image1" alt="alt text"/>
      <text id="1">36</text>
    </binding>
  </visual>
</tile>
```

The only change to the tile with this is that 36 is in the bottom left corner of the tile; however, all of the example template xml files they have work great.

(Note:  The template I am after is at the very bottom of the page.)

[image]

Comment: have you made it work ? if yes please help me i am kind of stuck here :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to send badge notification seperatly. following is the code on how to send badge notification after updating live tile

```
 XmlDocument badgeXml = BadgeUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(BadgeTemplateType.BadgeNumber); 
        XmlElement badgeElement = (XmlElement)badgeXml.SelectSingleNode("/badge");
        badgeElement.SetAttribute("value", "55");
        BadgeNotification badge = new BadgeNotification(badgeXml);
        BadgeUpdateManager.CreateBadgeUpdaterForApplication().Update(badge);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, but the above image (just posted it) is the one from the template. It is not a typical badge.

Answer (score 0):

The Badge must be sent separately, it's written in the description:

[image: badge]

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the tiles is a complete disaster! Here's the code that I'm using, I think I had to pull it from one of the sample projects, as it's not listed anywhere on the webpages themselves.

```
    public static TileNotification CreateMediumTile(int count)
    {
        // Get an XML DOM version of a specific template by using getTemplateContent.
        var tileXml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileSquare150x150IconWithBadge);

        // You will need to look at the template documentation to know how many text fields a particular template has.
        // Get the text attribute for this template and fill it in.
        var tileImage = tileXml.GetElementsByTagName("image");
        ((XmlElement)tileImage[0]).SetAttribute("src", "ms-appx:///Assets/SquareTile71x71.png");
        ((XmlElement)tileImage[0]).SetAttribute("alt", "My App Icon");

        BadgeNotification badge;

        if (count > 0)
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml("<badge version='3' value='" + count + "'/>");
            badge = new BadgeNotification(xmlDoc);

        }
        else
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml("<badge version='3' value='none'/>");
            badge = new BadgeNotification(xmlDoc);
        }

        // Send the notification to the application’s tile.
        BadgeUpdateManager.CreateBadgeUpdaterForApplication().Update(badge);

        // Create the notification from the XML.
        var tileNotification = new TileNotification(tileXml);

        return tileNotification;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's true that TileTemplateType enum not contains badge types TileSquare71x71IconWithBadge, TileSquare150x150IconWithBadge and TileWide310x150IconWithBadgeAndText but MSDN page '[The tile template catalog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx)' contains xml descriptions of this tiles definitions. And TileNotification could be constructed using code

```cs
var xml = "<tile><visual version=\"3\"><binding template=\"TileSquare71x71IconWithBadge\"><image id=\"1\" src=\"ms-appx:///Assets/BageLogo.scale-240.png\" alt=\"alt text\"/></binding></visual></tile>";

var tile = new XmlDocument();
tile.LoadXml(xml);
var tileNotification = new TileNotification(tile);

TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(tileNotification);
```

*Note* that image in this case it path to small bage icon.

And also badge number should be updated separately using BadgeUpdateManager. Code of badge update posted in previous answers...